# How to update an inherited entity when the specific discriminator must change?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'll try to be as clear as my bad english let me...

I have a tree defined on a database using nodes, this nodes cam be either sums, multiplications and any math operation, the base node entity is defined as this (is just a math operation represented as a tree on posfix notation)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Nodo")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

public abstract class Nodo implements java.io.Serializable, NumberExpressible {
```

and also I have many classes defining the type of nodes maped like this...

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SUM")
public class SumNode extends Nodo {
```

I have to use this child classes because each of them ha the specific logic to make the corresponding operations...

Now the porblem is that when I need to update the tree, I'm having many exceptions, to be more specific this is an example of what happening
()
for instance we have a simple tree like this (4+8)

But then I need to change it to: ((3*2) + 8)

If you see the first node of the second level in the first case is a constantNode and in the second case is a MultNode...so when I get the object from the entityManager im getting a constantNode, but then, when I need to change the type, It just won't change...The las thing I triyed was to detach the original entity and merge the "new" (isn't really new...its just the same info but a differente class instance..)

Any ideas??? I been stucked for like a week...please help I just need to be capable to update the nodes, actually just the discriminator...and don't wnat to make a direct update because I'm in a bigger trasac context and I'm not sure it whould afect something else

Comment: You don't, basically.  You can't change something's type.  This is not a use case for inheritance.  http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/02/10/Subtle-design-inheritance-vs-roles.aspx

Comment: remove the node and create a new mult node